# jQuery content fade in and navigation bar bounce in

Tags: jquery, css

I know it's possible with jQuery, but I'm having some serious troubles with this code for some reason. Could anyone help me write a small script that fades in the div of #content, and then after it's 100% opacity, have the navigation bar with the id of #links kind of fall in from above and bounce once? Like a super ball. :P I know this is possible, I just need someone to help me achieve it! Any help would be appreciated. Also, I wouldn't mind using CSS for this if anyone is really good at CSS and would know  how to achieve this, but jQuery is preferred. Sorry for so many questions today, I'm just learning jQuery (finally!) and it's all very confusing!

Comment: Where is your http://sscce.org/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way to do this is with a callback function once the fadeIn is complete, like this:

```
$("#content").fadeIn(1000,
          function(){
              $("#links").show();
          }
  );
```

Then you can replace the `show()` with some easing effects as described here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/#easing

The "easeInElastic" effect looks like something you could use.  But with all due respect, you should really make some effort on your own before you ask here for people to solve something for you.

I've seen this link going around a bit lately:
http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I was trying for almost 2 hours straight before I asked here.

Comment: @JamesCharless, fair enough.  But you didn't provide any examples of what you tried... or a JSFiddle, etc.  I'd encourage you to provide as much example work when asking similar questions, as it shows you've made some effort and makes people more willing to help you spot your issue.  Does the answer I provided above solve your problem?

Comment: I've already flagged my post for deletion because I solved it with a CSS3 tutorial I found, but yours worked fine also. CSS3: http://jamestestblog3.tumblr.com/

Comment: @JamesCharless, it's preferable for you to mark my solution correct if it works rather than delete it just because you found a different solution elsewhere.  Someone else might find this solution useful.